# Finding $E \left[\frac{1}{\bar{X}} \right]$ for $X_1, ...,X_n \sim_{iid} Geo(p)$

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I am trying to prove that the estimator $\hat{p}=\frac{1}{\bar{X}}$ is unbiased.

Since the $X_i$ s are iid geometric, I know that $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is negative binomial.

So what I want to do is

$$E[\hat{p}] = nE \left[ \frac{1}{Y} \right]=n\sum_{Y=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{Y} {Y-1 \choose n-1}p^n(1-p)^{y-n}$$

but I am not sure how to evaluate this.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\Bbb{E}}\newcommand{\x}{\bar{X}}$Actually, it will be biased. By Jensen's Inequality, you can show that $$\E\left[\frac{1}{\x}\right] > \frac{1}{\E\left[\x\right]}.$$

(Because the function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is strictly convex on the positive reals.)

Since $\E\left[\x\right] = \frac{1}{p}$, we have $  \frac{1}{\E\left[\x\right]} = p$, and so $$\E\left[\frac{1}{\x}\right]  > p.$$

Comment: Empirically $\mathbb E\left[\frac{1}{\bar X}\right] \approx p+\frac1np(1-p)$.  For example with $p=\frac12$ and $n=6$ you have $\mathbb E\left[\frac{1}{\bar X}\right]=4.7-6\log_e(2)\approx 0.5411$ while $p+\frac1np(1-p)=\frac{13}{24}\approx 0.5417$ and the approximation gets better with larger $n$.